# Java - force implementation of a method for each child of an abstract class

Tags: java, algorithm, abstract-class

I have an abstract class Action with children like SendMessageAction.

I would like to run these actions in a service but how could I force implementation of each child ?

For example I would like to implement an abstract method : void run(Action action) 
and methods "run" for each possible Action with an error if some methods are missing.

Any idea ?

Comment: "methods "run" for each possible Action with an error if some methods are missing" - can you explain that?

Comment: well, imagine Action have 2 child : SendMessageAction and RequestUrlAction. I want a "run" method for these 2 classes but not inside, these are pojo. And I would like a java error if one of "run" method is missing (i don't know where :D)

Comment: Use the Visitor Pattern (aka double dispatch)

Comment: Does it work if you put the keyword `abstract` before your function declaration in the abstract class?

Comment: Your question's wording is very much confusing.  You can't "implement an abstract method" more than once in a class, and that's what you seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should help you to get started. Happy coding!

**Action.java**

```
public abstract class Action {
   protected abstract void runAction(); 
}
```

**MessageSenderAction.java**

```
public class MessageSenderAction extends Action {

   public void runAction() {
       //send message
   }

}
```

**SomeOtherAction.java**

```
public class SomeOtherAction extends Action {

   public void runAction() {
       //do something else
   }
}
```

**ActionHandler.java**

```
public class  ActionHandler {

    private final static ActionHandler INSTANCE = new ActionHandler();

    private ActionHandler() {}

    public static ActionHandler getInstance() {
      return INSTANCE;
    }

    private List<Action> allActions = new ArrayList<Action>();


    public void addAction(Action action) {
        allActions.add(action);
    }

    public void runAllActions() {
        for(Action action: allActions) {
            //just to handle exception if there is any. Not to hamper other actions in case of any failures
            try {
                action.runAction();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ActionDemo.java**

```
public class ActionDemo {

   public static void main(String... args) {

    ActionHandler actionHandler = ActionHandler.getInstance();
    Action msgSenderAction = new MessageSenderAction();
    Action someOtherAction = new SomeOtherAction();
    actionHandler.addAction(msgSenderAction);
    actionHandler.addAction(someOtherAction);
    actionHandler.runAllActions();
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code ;) But I would like to avoir using a run method inside the POJO because I need some others autowired services..

Comment: I am sorry! I have never worked with POJO. But the idea might be helpful to you. Tweak it for your use.

Comment: If you looked up what POJO is, you'd have realized the impossibility of "not having worked with POJO" :)

Comment: Sure Marko! That is on the list! Will take a look.